# java gui help actionlistener

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to set a combobox in my GUI to print the the information about a student in a JLabel.

```
private void studentComboBoxMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    if combobox1="student1"{
        println.jlabel."name:a";
        println.jlabel.""age:12";
        println.jlabel."course:english";
    }

    if combobox1="student2"{
        println.jlabel."name:b";
        println.jlabel.""age:11";
        println.jlabel."course:maths";
    }

    if combobox1="student3"{
        println.jlabel."name:c";
        println.jlabel.""age:10";
        println.jlabel."course:science";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're just guessing, are you?

Comment: yep can anyone point me in the right direction

Comment: in your original question I meant to include a link to the Swing tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). Well the link got included but it was included at the start of my reply. Anyway the idea was for you to read the tutorial first because the tutorial has plenty of working examples. An ActionListener is simpler to use since you don't have to worry about the two events generated by the ItemListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen for itemstatechange on your combobox,
Upon selecting your student , fetch the selected item and operate on to display appropriate messages.

[Have a look at this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListentoJComboBoxwithItemListener.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a pseudocode, then it's correct. But in java the same code would be:

```
  if ("student1".equals(combobox1)) {
    jlabel.setText("name:a age:12 course:english");
  } else if ("student2".equals(combobox1)) {
    jlabel.setText(...);
  } else if ("student3".equals(combobox1)) {
    jlabel.setText(...);
  }
```

Of course, it works if `combobox1` is String, which holds the value of your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track but you need to read more tutorials. Start with the one suggested by Babban Shikaari. Your code should be something similar to this:

```
if (combobox.getSelectedItem().equals("student1")){
   jlabel.setText("Your new information");
}
```

Comment: just have 1 more questions, how can i get it to print each thing on a new line? would i be right in thinking replace "setText" with "println" e.g.jlabel.println("name: a");
jlabel.println("age: 12");

Comment: You would then either make several JLabels, on for each row. or include line breaks in your settext-method. I.e. jlabel.setText("Blah blah \n bla blah");